# Indefinite integral of $e^{x^n}$

Tags: integration, exponential-function, gamma-function

I came across this integral $\int e^{x^n} dx $ and was just wondering how you go about solving it. In this [Quora question](https://www.quora.com/What-is-the-integral-of-e-x-4) there approach is to let $y = -x^n$, then
$$
dy = -nx^{n-1} dx = -n(-y)^{\frac{n-1}{n}} \ dx \ \Rightarrow \ dx = -\frac{1}{n}(-y)^{\frac{1-n}{n}} \ dy,
$$
then sub into the integral, we have
$$
\int e^{x^n} dx = \frac{(-1)^{\frac{1}{n}-1}}{n}\int_{-\infty}^\infty  y^{\frac{1}{n}-1} e^{-y} \ dy,
$$
then they referenced the primary definition of incomplete gamma function,
$$
\Gamma(a,y) = \int_y^\infty t^{a-1} e^{-t} \ dt,
$$
and claim that we can write our integral in terms of $\Gamma$ function, and the end result is
$$
\int e^{x^n} dx = \frac{(-1)^{\frac{1}{n}-1}}{n} \Gamma(\frac{1}{n}, y).
$$
Can anyone fill in the missing step for me? Our integral does look very similar to the gamma function, but what happened to the lower bound of the integral? In our integral the lower bound is $-\infty$; but to equate it to the gamma function we need the lower bound to be $y$.

Anyway substitute back the definition of $y$ we have the final result
$$
\int e^{x^n} dx = \frac{(-1)^{\frac{1}{n}-1}}{n} \Gamma(\frac{1}{n}, -x^n).
$$
I̶'̶m̶ ̶g̶u̶e̶s̶s̶i̶n̶g̶ ̶t̶h̶e̶i̶r̶ ̶a̶n̶s̶w̶e̶r̶ ̶i̶s̶ ̶c̶o̶r̶r̶e̶c̶t̶ ̶b̶e̶c̶a̶u̶s̶e̶ ̶M̶a̶t̶h̶e̶m̶a̶t̶i̶c̶a̶ ̶a̶l̶s̶o̶ ̶g̶i̶v̶e̶s̶ ̶t̶h̶e̶ ̶s̶a̶m̶e̶ ̶r̶e̶s̶u̶l̶t̶.̶ ̶B̶u̶t̶ ̶a̶n̶o̶t̶h̶e̶r̶ ̶t̶h̶i̶n̶g̶ ̶I̶ ̶d̶o̶n̶'̶t̶ ̶u̶n̶d̶e̶r̶s̶t̶a̶n̶d̶ ̶i̶s̶ ̶w̶h̶y̶ ̶d̶o̶e̶s̶ ̶t̶h̶e̶ ̶i̶n̶t̶e̶g̶r̶a̶l̶ ̶d̶e̶p̶e̶n̶d̶s̶ ̶o̶n̶ ̶$̶x̶$̶?̶ ̶Y̶o̶u̶'̶d̶ ̶t̶h̶i̶n̶k̶ ̶$̶x̶$̶ ̶s̶h̶o̶u̶l̶d̶ ̶b̶e̶ ̶i̶n̶t̶e̶g̶r̶a̶t̶e̶d̶ ̶o̶v̶e̶r̶.̶ Any help is appreciated, thanks.

Comment: Hmm I just assumed it was correct because that's also the result given by Mathematica. I'm not sure how to verify it, as I don't know what $x$ should be and why the RHS depends on $x$ in the first place.

Comment: "But another thing I don't understand is why does the integral depends on ?" Do you understand why $\int 2x{\rm d}x = x^2 +C$ depends on $x$? An indefinite integral (an anti-derivative) is a function (with a free integration constant). A definite integral (when the integral has limits) is a number.

Comment: Ugh I confused indefinite integrals with integrals with bounds $-\infty$ to $\infty$. Thanks for the reply.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$\newcommand{\d}{\mathrm{d}}$
$\newcommand{\e}{\mathrm{e}}$

We can evade confusion by working exclusively with parametrized definite integrals and using different symbols for bound and free variables. Consider

$$\begin{align}I(x)&=\int_0^x\e^{u^{\nu}}\d u\text{,}& \nu &>0\text{.}
\end{align}$$
Set
$$\begin{align}
t&=-u^{\nu}&
\d t &= -\nu u^{\nu-1}\d u\text{.}
\end{align}$$
Then
$$\begin{split}I(x)&=\frac{(-1)^{(1/\nu) - 1}}{\nu}\left(\int_0^{-x^{\nu}}t^{(1/\nu) - 1}\e^{-t}\d t\right)\\
&=\frac{(-1)^{(1/\nu) - 1}}{\nu}\left( \Gamma(\tfrac{1}{\nu},-x^{\nu})-\Gamma(\tfrac{1}{\nu})\right) \end{split}$$

Answer (score 0):

Also notice that:
$$e^y=\sum_{i=0}^\infty\frac{y^i}{i!}$$
And so:
$$e^{x^n}=\sum_{i=0}^\infty\frac{x^{ni}}{i!}$$
And so:
$$\int e^{x^n}dx=\int\sum_{i=0}^\infty\frac{x^{ni}}{i!}dx=\sum_{i=0}^\infty\int\frac{x^{ni}}{i!}dx=\sum_{i=0}^\infty\frac{x^{ni+1}}{i!(ni+1)}$$