# How does one evaluate $\int {e^{x^n}}dx$, where $n$ is a natural number?

Tags: calculus, integration, indefinite-integrals, gamma-function

I have quite an interesting question to ask.

**How does one evaluate the following indefinite integral?**

$$I = \int {e^{x^n}}dx$$

Note: $n$ is a natural number ($n = 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, ...$).

---

It would be best if the [incomplete gamma function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Incomplete_gamma_function#Definition) is used:

$$\Gamma (s, x) = \int^{\infty}_x {t^{s - 1}e^{-t}}dt$$

Here is what I have done:

$$I = \int {e^{x^n}}dx$$

$$\text {Let } y = - x^n\text {.}$$

$$\frac {dy}{dx} = - n x^{n - 1}$$

$$dx = \cfrac {dy}{-nx^{n - 1}}$$

$$\text {Since } y = - x^n\text {,}$$

$$x = (-y)^{\frac {1}{n}}$$

$$\text {Therefore,}$$

$$dx = \frac {dy}{-n(-y)^{{\frac {1}{n}}{(n - 1)}}}$$

$$\text {Thus,}$$

$$I = \int {e^{-y}\cdot {\frac {dy}{-n(-y)^{{\frac {1}{n}}{(n - 1)}}}}}$$

$$I = -\frac {1}{n}\int {e^{-y}\cdot {(-y)^{{-\frac {1}{n}}{(n - 1)}}} \; dy}$$

$$I = -\frac {1}{n}\int {(-y)^{\frac {1}{n} - 1}}\cdot {e^{-y} \; dy}$$

**How does one proceed to incorporate the incomplete gamma function?**

Looking forward to a response! Also, I'm still new to MSE, so I would really appreciate any and all feedback. Thank you!

Comment: I would think that setting $\frac{1}{n}$ as $s$, factoring out the $(-1)^{\frac{1}{n}-1}$ and setting $y$ to $t$ would suffce.

Comment: Ah, I see. Thank you very much.

Comment: if $y$ is positive then $(-y)^{\frac1n-1}$ is not defined, at least as a real number.

Comment: @Masacroso We have assumed $y = -x^n$, so $-y = x^n$. I assume that is the correct explanation. But, I believe the final answer is not defined as a real number.

Comment: $$\int e^{x^n} \, dx=-\frac{x \left(-x^n\right)^{-1/n} \Gamma \left(\frac{1}{n},-x^n\right)}{n}$$

Comment: @Raffaele Oh, I got: $$\int e^{x^n} \; dx = -\frac{\left(-1\right)^{(1/n) - 1}}{n}\Gamma \left(\frac {1}{n} ,-x^n\right)$$

Comment: @AnitejPalur my result comes from *Wolfram Mathematica*. Taking the derivative, your result gives $(-1)^{\frac{n+2}{n}} e^{x^n}$ while Mathematica's result gives exactly $e^{x^n}$

Comment: FYI - the strict answer to the question you asked is "$I$ is *defined* to be the family of functions $f$ satisfying $f'(x) = e^{x^n}$". The word you intended is "evaluate", not "define".

Comment: @Raffaele Oh, okay. Thank you very much for the clarification.

Comment: @PaulSinclair Thank you very much. I have edited the question accordingly.

Comment: @PaulSinclair will taking $m = x^n$ and then integrating work here ?

Comment: I'm sorry, but I was just drawing your attention to a minor wording issue in your question. I am barely familiar with the incomplete gamma function.

Comment: @PaulSinclair No worries. I thought you had made the comment regarding taking the substitution $m = x^n$. My apologies.

Comment: @Spectre We are taking $y=−x^n$ so that we can express the integral with $e^{−y}$, which makes it easier to incorporate the incomplete gamma function.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Indefinite integral of $e^{x^n}$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3359082/indefinite-integral-of-exn)

Comment: @HansLundmark I apologise for the late response. The answers there are slightly beyond my level of understanding, though they do pick on several important points. I will have to look at them more closely. I appreciate the help.